# How to add incrementing numbers before file extension .mp3

Tags: filenames, rename, macos

Aloha from Hawaii,

I hope all is well. In terminal, am trying to make all the filenames of the audio files extensions .mp3, .wav, .m4p, .aiff, .m4a to be unique. I have thousands of them so in order to do this, I need to additional incrementing numbers right before their file extension. The filename should remain.

For example:
snoopdog.mp3,
music2010.wav,
stackexchange.aiff,
youtubemusic.mp3,
facebookmusic.m4a,
twittermusic.aiff

End result:
snoopdog1.mp3,
music20102.wav,
stackexchange3.aiff,
youtubemusic4.mp3,
facebookmusic5.m4a,
twittermusic6.aiff

Please how to do this in terminal. Thanks!

Comment: If the filenames are not currently unique, they must be spread across several directories, right? Can you say something about how the files are currently arranged and how you want them to be arranged after changing their names?

Comment: All files are currently in the same directory and I'm not saying anything to arrange them. I only want to change their names by adding incrementing numbers before the file extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
i=1
for file in ./*; do
    ext=${file##*.}
    basename=${file%.*}
    mv -n -- "$file" "$basename$i.$ext"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

would give you `facebookmusic1.m4a music20102.wav snoopdog3.mp3 stackexchange4.aiff twittermusic5.aiff youtubemusic6.mp3`. The ordering comes form the default lexicographic sort, so the letter `f` comes first etc.

That would rename all files in the current directory, but if you want to only change files with that expression, you could do either

```
for file in *.mp3 *.aiff *.m4a *.wav; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        ...
    fi
done
```

or

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in *.@(mp3|aiff|m4a|wav); do
    ...
```

where the first should work in all shells, but would affect the sort order, and the latter would work in Bash. (The same works in ksh without needing the `shopt`, or use `*.(mp3|aiff|m4a|wav)` in zsh.)

---

With the Perl `rename` tool, abusing the special status of the `$a` and `$b` variables, you could do this to a similar effect (though this will replace at the first dot if there are multiple):

```
rename -v 's/\./ ++$a . "." /e' *
```

Comment: All of your codes works! Really appreciate it, this really helps a lot! Thank you so much!  @ilkkachu

Comment: +1. `rename -n 's/(\.[^.]*)$/ ++$i . $1 /e' *` would add the counter only before the final "extension".   IMO, `'s/(\.[^.]*)$/sprintf ".%03i%s", ++$i, $1/e'` would be even better - e.g. it would rename `foo.bar.mp3` to `foo.bar.001.mp3`.   I'm not sure what you mean by "special status of the `$a` and `$b` variables", you're only using `$a` as an auto-incrementing counter ($a & $b are only special inside a `sort` function...although there are good reasons to avoid messing with their scope, or just avoiding them altogether outside of sort - I used `$i` instead, `i` is kind of traditional anyway)

Comment: @badua1256 the `sprintf` function provides a lot of flexibility and precise control of how files are renamed with perl `rename` scripts.  You can use regex grouping (like the `(...)` and `$1` I used above to extract the extension) see `perldoc -f sprintf` and `man perlre`. It's worth reading the Perl Regex Tutorial too (`man perlretut`).

Comment: @cas, Well, I tried `$i` at first, but at least with the version of `rename` I have, I got "Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $i"?) at (user-supplied code)." `$a` and `$b` are special in that they're already there, and don't need to be declared so it works with them. Yes, otherwise I'd have not used them outside `sort()`, and that's why I called it "abusing" them. I'm not exactly sure if `rename` is meant to be used with stateful code like that...

Comment: duh, I forgot the important bit. Add `our $i;` to the start of the rename script. `rename -n 'our $i; s/(\.[^.]*)$/ ++$i . $1 /e' *`. rename runs with `strict` active, and you need to be careful of variable scope. `my` variables are OK for variables that will be `undef` after each filename, but variables that need to keep their values (like auto-incrementing counters) need to be `our` variables (i.e. in the lexical scope of the File::Rename package). See `perldoc -f our` and `perldoc -f my`.  Another alternative would be to explicitly use the pkg name: `$File::Rename::i` instead of just `$i`.

Comment: or just use $a or $b :-). As you say, they're already global scope, and as long as you don't redefine them to be local and then use them in sort, it should be OK.

Comment: @cas, ah yes, that's the way, thanks. I don't _really_ do Perl, and I never remember how scoping in Perl actually works...